# Loop through multiple json input files

Tags: python, loops

I have over 200 scraped files in json format and I want to analyse them.  I can open them individually, but would like to loop through to save time as I will be doing this a lot.

Can open each file but want to be able to do a loop in some format
e.g.

```
with codecs.open('c:\\project\\input*.json','r','utf-8') as f:
```

where '*' is a number.....

```
import codecs, json, csv, re

#read a json file downloaded with twitterscraper

with codecs.open('c:\\project\\input1.json','r','utf-8') as f:
    tweets = json.load(f,encoding='utf-b')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put your files into a folder and then loop through the files in the folder like so.

```
import codecs
import json
import csv
import re
import os

files = []
for file in os.listdir("/mydir"):
    if file.endswith(".json"):
        files.append(os.path.join("/mydir", file))

for file in files:
    with codecs.open(file,'r','utf-8') as f: 
        tweets = json.load(f,encoding='utf-b')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add, and use, [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#module-glob) to iterate over files with certain file pattern.

```
import glob
import codecs
import json
# ... more packages here

for file in glob.glob('c:\\project\\input*.json'):
    with codecs.open(file, 'r','utf-8') as f: 
        tweets = json.load(f, encoding='utf-b')
        #... whatever you do next with `tweets`
```

*BTW: utf-b instead of utf-8?*